# How to collect trainable variables of the generator and discriminator? (Tensorflow)

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I would like to implement Generative Adversarial Networks following [this tutorial](https://wiseodd.github.io/techblog/2016/09/17/gan-tensorflow/)

Unfortunately I have no idea how to apply this part in my project:

```
# Only update D(X)'s parameters, so var_list = theta_D
D_solver = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(D_loss, var_list=theta_D)
# Only update G(X)'s parameters, so var_list = theta_G
G_solver = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(G_loss, var_list=theta_G)
```

I have a more complex network, where the layers are initialized by reusable functions, and I am not able to collect the variables in `theta_D` and `theta_G` by hand.

I've placed the generator and discriminator layers into named scopes. Is it possible to collect the variables after building the network, and then pass it to the `AdamOptimizer().minimize(...)` ?

This code gives me an empty result:

```
tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope='discriminator')
```

---

**Edit**

I tried to call `tf.get_collection` inside a named scope and I get some results. But if I replace `theta_G` and `theta_D` from the [example](https://github.com/wiseodd/generative-models/blob/master/GAN/vanilla_gan/gan_tensorflow.py) code with this, the model is not able to learn:

```
with tf.name_scope('G_sample'):
    G_sample = generator(Z)
    theta_G = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES)

with tf.name_scope('D_real'):
    D_real, D_logit_real = discriminator(X)
    theta_D = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES)
```

No matter how long I run the training, it returns noise instead of the image. The wrong variables are selected, but I have no idea why

---

**Edit2**

I modified the example code according to [vijay m's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50425938/). It runs without error, but it does not learn. The result is noise.

The full code is:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import os


def xavier_init(size):
    in_dim = size[0]
    xavier_stddev = 1. / tf.sqrt(in_dim / 2.)
    return tf.random_normal(shape=size, stddev=xavier_stddev)


X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784])
Z = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 100])


def sample_Z(m, n):
    return np.random.uniform(-1., 1., size=[m, n])


def generator(z, reuse=False):

    with tf.variable_scope('generator', reuse=reuse):

        G_W1 = tf.Variable(xavier_init([100, 128]))
        G_b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=[128]))

        G_W2 = tf.Variable(xavier_init([128, 784]))
        G_b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=[784]))

        #

        G_h1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(z, G_W1) + G_b1)
        G_log_prob = tf.matmul(G_h1, G_W2) + G_b2
        G_prob = tf.nn.sigmoid(G_log_prob)

    return G_prob


def discriminator(x, reuse=False):

    with tf.variable_scope('discriminator', reuse=reuse):

        D_W1 = tf.Variable(xavier_init([784, 128]))
        D_b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=[128]))

        D_W2 = tf.Variable(xavier_init([128, 1]))
        D_b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=[1]))

        #

        D_h1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x, D_W1) + D_b1)
        D_logit = tf.matmul(D_h1, D_W2) + D_b2
        D_prob = tf.nn.sigmoid(D_logit)

    return D_prob, D_logit


def plot(samples):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4, 4))
    gs = gridspec.GridSpec(4, 4)
    gs.update(wspace=0.05, hspace=0.05)

    for i, sample in enumerate(samples):
        ax = plt.subplot(gs[i])
        plt.axis('off')
        ax.set_xticklabels([])
        ax.set_yticklabels([])
        ax.set_aspect('equal')
        plt.imshow(sample.reshape(28, 28), cmap='Greys_r')

    return fig



G_sample = generator(Z)
D_real, D_logit_real = discriminator(X)

t_vars = tf.trainable_variables()
theta_D = [var for var in t_vars if var.name.startswith('discriminator')]
theta_G = [var for var in t_vars if var.name.startswith('generator')]

D_fake, D_logit_fake = discriminator(G_sample)

# Alternative losses:
# -------------------
D_loss_real = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=D_logit_real, labels=tf.ones_like(D_logit_real)))
D_loss_fake = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=D_logit_fake, labels=tf.zeros_like(D_logit_fake)))
D_loss = D_loss_real + D_loss_fake
G_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=D_logit_fake, labels=tf.ones_like(D_logit_fake)))

D_solver = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(D_loss, var_list=theta_D)
G_solver = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(G_loss, var_list=theta_G)

mb_size = 128
Z_dim = 100

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('../../MNIST_data', one_hot=True)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

if not os.path.exists('out/'):
    os.makedirs('out/')

i = 0

for it in range(1000000):
    if it % 1000 == 0:
        samples = sess.run(G_sample, feed_dict={Z: sample_Z(16, Z_dim)})

        fig = plot(samples)
        plt.savefig('out/{}.png'.format(str(i).zfill(3)), bbox_inches='tight')
        i += 1
        plt.close(fig)

    X_mb, _ = mnist.train.next_batch(mb_size)

    _, D_loss_curr = sess.run([D_solver, D_loss], feed_dict={X: X_mb, Z: sample_Z(mb_size, Z_dim)})
    _, G_loss_curr = sess.run([G_solver, G_loss], feed_dict={Z: sample_Z(mb_size, Z_dim)})

    if it % 1000 == 0:
        print('Iter: {}'.format(it))
        print('D loss: {:.4}'. format(D_loss_curr))
        print('G_loss: {:.4}'.format(G_loss_curr))
        print()
```

theta_D:

```
[<tf.Variable 'discriminator/Variable:0' shape=(784, 128) dtype=float32_ref>, <tf.Variable 'discriminator/Variable_1:0' shape=(128,) dtype=float32_ref>, <tf.Variable 'discriminator/Variable_2:0' shape=(128, 1) dtype=float32_ref>, <tf.Variable 'discriminator/Variable_3:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>]
```

theta_G:

```
[<tf.Variable 'generator/Variable:0' shape=(100, 128) dtype=float32_ref>, <tf.Variable 'generator/Variable_1:0' shape=(128,) dtype=float32_ref>, <tf.Variable 'generator/Variable_2:0' shape=(128, 784) dtype=float32_ref>, <tf.Variable 'generator/Variable_3:0' shape=(784,) dtype=float32_ref>]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Can be done by the following steps:**

Define `variable scopes` for `discriminator` and `generator`:

```
def discriminator(x, reuse=False)
    with tf.variable_scope('discriminator', reuse=reuse):
    ...

def generator(z, output_dim, reuse=False, alpha=0.2, training=True):
    with tf.variable_scope('generator', reuse=reuse):
    ...
```

Get the parameters of both `discriminator` and `generator`:

```
# Get weights and bias to update
t_vars = tf.trainable_variables()
theta_D = [var for var in t_vars if var.name.startswith('discriminator')]
theta_G = [var for var in t_vars if var.name.startswith('generator')]
```

In the example code, your variables needs to be declared within the scope, like:

```
def generator(z, reuse=False):

  with tf.variable_scope('generator', reuse=reuse):

    G_W1 = tf.Variable(xavier_init([100, 128]))
    G_b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=[128]))

    G_W2 = tf.Variable(xavier_init([128, 784]))
    G_b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=[784]))

    G_h1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(z, G_W1) + G_b1)
    G_log_prob = tf.matmul(G_h1, G_W2) + G_b2
    G_prob = tf.nn.sigmoid(G_log_prob)

    return G_prob
```

Then you can check the variables for the generator doing:

```
 print([var for var in tf.trainable_variables() if var.name.startswith('generator')])
```

Comment: I cant downvote my own answer, and i didnt do it to yours as well.

Comment: the variables need to be declared within the scope, added details.

Comment: Because of the `discriminator(G_sample)` part, `theta_D` contains all of the 8 variables, not just the ones from the discriminator. How it it possible to avoid that?

Comment: I updated the question with the full code, and theta values

Comment: Yes, if I get t_vars before `discriminator(G_sample)`. But it is not able to learn for some reason